# PHP Uploads all failing

Tags: php, file-upload, upload

Due to unknown reasons since a few days my Plesk server will no longer collaborate with PHP file uploads.

Testing was done with a 1.8 MB mp3 file and an even smaller movie file.

I tried to debug my way through this issue..

upload_max_filesize = 100M

post_max_size = 128M

open_basedir is either off or set to two directories, one of them being /tmp/

upload_tmp_dir = /tmp
memory_limit = 4096M (due to other reasons this is set extra high)

/tmp comes like this:

```
drwxrwxrwx   4 root root  200 Mar 29 14:09 tmp
```

Linux version 2.6.32-5-amd64 (Debian 2.6.32-35) (dannf@debian.org) (gcc version 4.3.5 (Debian 4.3.5-4) ) #1 SMP Tue Jun 14 09:42:28 UTC 2011

My forms use multipart/form-data, so this is settled, although i also tested with two different ajax upload scripts - both of which usually work just fine.

I get no error messages whatsoever. All i know is that the tmp file is not there after uploading. And that's that.

Does anyone know what is going on here?

Thank You!

Comment: How many disk space is left on the server? /tmp may be cleared at any moment in time.

Comment: 29% usage on main disk. However, i found this: Filesystem "overflow" is mounted on /tmp (what does that mean?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in your comments you have a `overflow` mounted on top of `/tmp`. This behaviour actually indicates, that /tmp is full, because if /tmp is full a script `/etc/init.d/mountoverflowtmp` will automatically create a RAM-disk that is 1mb in size. So I suggest to `umount overflow` and then to clean up your `/tmp`

Answer (score 1):

I image somewhere in your code you access $_FILE array to get the uploaded file.

try this:

```
 print_r($_FILES);
```

If the problem is php related you will see "error code" set.

Here is an error codes explanation:
http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

This can help you identifying the problem

Answer (score 0):

> "All i know is that the tmp file is not there after uploading. And
>   that's that."

Do you mean that you are looking for it manually after you run the script?  If that is the case, that is the expected behavior.  The file is temporarily stored in $_FILES['postVariableName']['tmp_name'] and will be removed at the end of the script unless you do something w/the file first.

```
$localFilePath='/some/file/path.txt';
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['postVariableName']['tmp_name'], $localFilePath)){
   //Successfully moved the file
}
else{
   //Unable to move file
   echo'Could not move file';
}
```